# Question about prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create some rules and facts on a certain situation. The situation is such that if a user owes money then he is said to be in debt after 5 days if it is not repaid, if he doesn't then he is a normal person. So far i'm experimenting with something like:

I have two rules:

```
debtpayment_unfulfilled(X) :- owes_money(W, Amountowed, Amountpaid, Days), Days >= 7,Amountowed > Amountpaid. .
debtpayment_fulfilled(X) :- debt_paid(W,Amountowed,Amountpaid), Amountowed =:= Amountpaid.
owes_money(jim, 500, 200, 8).
```

But i can't seem to get it to compile, XSB tells me there is an unbound variable expr in clause #1...

any ideas?  edit scrap that, I have just got it to compile lol, typo, btw does the ruling look right for what im trying to do?
when i try running it, i cant get an answer with the query:

```
debtpayment_unfulfilled(jim).
```

edit:

is it possible to do something like this:

```
debtpayment_unfulfilled(X) :- owes_money(X, Amountowed, Amountpaid, Days), Days >= Days + 7,Amountowed > Amountpaid.
```

the days + 7 bit or is that not possible?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this: `Days >= Days + 7`

Comment: actually maybe it should be Days +7 >= Days? What I need to try and get it to do is once 7 days have passed this part of the statement will be true, but the problem is for example owes_money(jim,5,2,8) - jim started owing money on day 8 so hopefully you see the problem?

Comment: Ok, first of all, it's better to ask a new question for every new problem you have, because editing the same question over and over makes it difficult to follow (and the same goes for answers). Now, an expression of the form Days + 7 >= Days (or Days >= Days + 7) makes no sense, because once Days gets bound to a value, the expression will always be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you use different variable names in `debtpayment_unfulfilled` and `owes_money`. Try this:

```
debtpayment_unfulfilled(X) :- owes_money(X, Amountowed, Amountpaid, Days), Days >= 7,Amountowed > Amountpaid.
debtpayment_fulfilled(X) :- debt_paid(X, Amountowed, Amountpaid), Amountowed =:= Amountpaid.
owes_money(jim, 500, 200, 8).
```

Comment: cheers, i think it did the trick, but i was wondering, instead of having two rules for fulfilled/unfulfilled wouldnt it be better jsut to have say the first one(unfulfilled) as it would tell you if a debt as been paid and also if it has not been paid if it evaluates to false?

Comment: I didn't give much thought to the semantics before. Yes, given that fulfilled/unfulfilled are exact opposites (that can't be seen the way they're formulated now), it would be better to have only one rule.